# JComboBox getSelectedItem() not changing

Tags: java, swing, binding, netbeans6.5

I'm binding a `JComboBox` to an observable `List`. I clear and add `Objects` form the observable list. This works fine and reflects the changes in the `JComboBox` correctly.

The problem is I can't select the content of the list using the mouse although the newly added items are correctly displayed in the combobox when expanded. The `getSelectedItem()` is always stuck on the first item in the list.

```
 List<Object> sourceListObserver = 
     ObservableCollections.observableList(new ArrayList<Object>());
```

The binding is done using Netbeans GUI designer.

I have now also tried using `DefaultComboBoxModel`.

```
DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
wireSourceComboBox.setModel(model);
```

Using `wireSourceComboBox.removeAllItems();` and `wireSourceComboBox.addItem(qb);`

Still the same behaviour after removing and adding objects to the combobox.

Comment: Please, can you specify the way you are selecting JCB value? How your model looks like?

Comment: I have edited the question, hope this answers you comment.

Comment: I've noticed that  I highlight the items by moving the mouse over then and then pressing enter it works. Really strange.

Comment: You need to post a working example

Answer (score 0):

without a working example it's hard to prove, but you probably need to fire the event listeners to have the UI track your model correctly.

see [AbstractListModel.fireContentsChanged](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractListModel.html#fireContentsChanged%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29)